# strstr issue in C

Tags: c, stm32, strstr

I'm using strstr to search for the beginning and end of brackets so I can filter out incorrect entries sent on the UART from information I actually want/need.

I have my UART interrupt storing characters into an array and incrementing the counter.  Below is the code in my main function:

```
  volatile char     UART_RX_Buffer[128]; // updated in UART
  volatile uint16_t UART_Byte_Counter = 0; // updated in UART
  
  while (1)
  {
        if(strstr(&UART_RX_Buffer[0], "{") != NULL)
        {
            if(strstr(&UART_RX_Buffer[0], "}") != NULL)
            {
                char *ret;
                int startindex;

                ret = strstr(&UART_RX_Buffer[0], "{");
                startindex = (ret - UART_RX_Buffer);

                // Clear out UART array and counter
                char Empty_Buffer[128] = {0};
                memcpy (UART_RX_Buffer, Empty_Buffer, sizeof(UART_RX_Buffer));
                UART_Byte_Counter = 0;
            }
        }
  }
```

So if I send it, say 012{345,678}, it will set the startindex as 3 (which is what I want).  It's successfully entering the loop, setting startindex, and clearing the UART_RX_Buffer and counter correctly.

What's odd is it only works the first time through.  If I send it a second time, I can see the buffer is holding the same data as the first time around . . . but it's not entering the first loop, recognizing the "{" character.  I can see an issue if I'm not doing things correctly with the UART interrupt and the buffer isn't being filled correctly . . . but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I don't really understand why I would get different results with what appears to be the same data (especially if I can confirm the data is in the UART buffer when trying to run that line).

Clearly I'm missing something.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  If it helps, it's an STM32L4R5ZI chip (though I would assume this is a C issue and not device specific).  I'll include screenshots from the debugger all the same in case it helps.  Thanks in advance[image]!

Comment: In your "second attempt", the first byte in the array is 0, and the string starts at index 1. So the `strstr()` won't find anything, since the string is empty (starts with a 0).

Comment: This isn't your issue, but you can likely say `memset(UART_RX_Buffer, '\0', sizeof(UART_RX_Buffer))` instead of that memcpy thing.

Comment: @selbie that is a much cleaner suggestion!  I knew there was a way to do it but I couldn't remember what the command was.  Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: `ret = strstr(&UART_RX_Buffer[0], "{");` This is terribly inefficient. You already found that result in your first `if` condition. Instead of searching again, just store the result on first call: `if ((ret = strstr(...)) != NULL)`. Also, if you are only looking for a single character, `strchr` might be more efficient than `strstr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> strstr issue in c

No, it is always your code issue. `strstr`, the compiler, linker and the silicon are OK.

> (especially if I can confirm the data is in the UART buffer when
> trying to run that line).

But it is not the data you think you have :)

[image]
The C sting is **empty** as it starts with the **null terminating character**. `strstr` sees the empty string. Your buffer-filling algorithm is definitely broken.

I can even tell you that you have not updated the index or pointer of the current buffer position as `'0'` goes to the place where the previous transition ended:
[image]

Comment: sorry, I worded that incorrectly.  I didn't mean to imply the issue was with the function itself, rather I was having issues when using it.  As you pointed out, the issue was with my interrupt.  

Essentially, at the end of the UART interrupt, I set the location of the where the next byte will be received, which was the byte counter incremented, as you pointed out).  Even though I zeroed out the byte counter, it wasn't updating the position the next bit of data was saving to.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to change the new interrupt location?  I tried adding "HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t*)&UART_RX_Buffer[0], 1);" to the end of my loop after clearing the byte counter but it still seems to want to want to keep it set to the previous counter location regardless.

Comment: I could fill the array with 1's instead of 0's, I guess.  I though using strstr instead of strtok got around the null termination issue but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Simply do not do it this way. You do not want IT version, only blocking

Comment: @BobDole nom because then you will not have null terminating character. Basically your algorithm is wrong and any workarounds will not correct the main issue.

Comment: It looks like I can do HAL_UART_Abort_IT(&hlpuart1); before re-initializing the interrupt.  What's the issue with this approach?  I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

The root of all your problems is nothing mentioned so far. But merely the fact that strings send over UART, from example through a PC terminal, *are unlikely to be null terminated*. They are not C strings! Far more likely, they are terminated by a single line feed `'\n'` or in case of Windows perhaps carriage return + line feed, `\r\n`.

This means that standard library string handling functions cannot be used. Forget about `strstr`, `strchr` and similar. You can only use those on null terminated strings (aka "C strings").

If you know the length of the data received - you should know this by counting the bytes received - you could use `memchr`. Or alternatively just parse the data manually, which might be the most efficient if you are looking for a particular format anyway.

But before doing anything else, figure out how you know where a string ends. Is there line feed, null termination, perhaps a size counter in the UART packet etc. Don't just assume one particular format - programming cannot be done through guessing.

---

Furthermore, this code here is not "thread safe", or interrupt safe in this case. You cannot read directly from a buffer that an ISR is filling up at any moment - not without some means of synchronization. A busy flag, disabling the ISR temporarily etc. Interrupts are *difficult* to work with and sometimes it seems that barely any programmer implements them correctly.

There are three sensible ways to implement UART Rx functionality:

- DMA (highly recommended). If the MCU supports this, it solves all problems with buffering and repeated interrupts, and makes "thread safety" much easier. You can generally work with one part of the DMA buffer while the UART works with another part.
- Ring buffers + ISR. The old school way when you've got an UART peripheral with limited hardware buffers. You implement a ring buffer ADT, optionally with thread-safety support built in, and all the ISR does is to add to it.
- Buffer swaps + ISR. The simplest way is to allocate two buffers (double buffering) and have a pointer point at the active one. The ISR will fill one buffer while the background program works with the other one. When the ISR has filled the buffer, you swap them by changing where the pointer points at. You'll never do slow `memcpy` that way.